# Single SSL cert on multiple servers

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, wildcard-subdomain

For a project I'm working on I will have multiple servers and lots of subdomains (eg- `*.mydomain.example`). I'm thinking of getting this SSL cert from godaddy- Unlimited Subdomains (Wildcard) $199.99/yr

Will I be able to use the cert on all the servers or do I need to buy a cert for each server since they each have a unique IP address?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Certificates are bound to a hostname (or wildcard hostname), so you're fine using the same cert on multiple machines.

However, when requesting a certificate, you usually create a private key on one of the servers. This private key needs to be copied to all machines in addition to the actual certificate that you receive.

One scenario is where you have `www.domain.example` resolving to an IP of a load-balancer, which in turn forwards the traffic to multiple servers. In that case, you only need a certificate for `www.domain.example` that you copy (with the private key) to all servers in your cluster.

Comment: Can I use same ssl certs for 443 and 8443?

Comment: @HussainTamboli, yes, that should be fine. Certs are only host-based, not port based.

Comment: @jishi  I've certificate for *.abc.com and Can i use this certificate for dev.abc.com:9003 ?

Comment: @rgx Yes, that should be fine. Port doesn't matter, and if it's a proper wildcard it would match dev.abc.com. Do note that wildcard certs only match one level up, meaning, *.abc.com won't match foo.dev.abc.com, only dev.abc.com.

Comment: @jishi thnks, resolved error. Issue is the 9003 port is used for http, So that  I've add new port 7003 for https and it's working (bcoz same port can not use for http and https).